# Alhazen's problem history

Tags: optics, mathematics-social-history, physics-social-history

I was wondering if anyone has read '' alhazen book of optics'' and has understood his solution of Alhazen's problem.

I know a modern solution of the problem by Dörrie-100 great problems of mathematics, but I'm interested really in ibn alhaytham's solution. I'm just curious about how he went about solving the problem without the modern tools. Also I couldn't find the problem in his book, maybe I didn't look carefully for it, but it would be nice if someone could reference me to it in his book also.

Comment: Please supply more precise references.

Comment: Wikipedia in French is perhaps more informative and gives a link to a paper by A. Sabra https://www2.kenyon.edu/Depts/Math/Aydin/Teach/128/AlHazenProblem.pdf